# Do Bluegene systems support ltdl or any other kind of dlopen() support?

Tags: c++, dynamic, loading, libtool, hpc

so I have some code that uses `dlopen` for loading libraries, and I want it to work on a bluegene system, but I don't have a bluegene to test things on, and I've never directly worked with one.  Does bluegene support `ltdl.h`, or does it use something else? if so, what does it use?

Comment: Even if it has `dlopen()` you would need run-time testing to ensure your code works as expected anyway.

Comment: well, there are people who would be abe to test it relatively quickly for me, but I'm not "sitting in front of one" so to speak, so I can't just muck around and try things and see if they run.  I'm not just going to write something and deploy it without doing any testing haha

Comment: @Sam BlueGene/L or BlueGene/P? Also +1 for a BlueGene question.

Comment: BlueGene/L, would the answer be different for /P?

Comment: @Sam: you need to be able to at least cross-compile for it.

Comment: I guess I should have elaborated a bit.  The code in question supports all major platforms, plus bluegene/L.  We have a testing setup in place to ensure that everything actually works.  I haven't actually started doing any work with dynamic loading, and if the answer to this question is "no", I'm just going to abandon this line of development and solve my problem another way.

Comment: @Sam the BG/P software stack is very different than BG/L, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693300/do-bluegene-systems-support-ltdl-or-any-other-kind-of-dlopen-support/4693807#4693807)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BlueGene/L does not support dynamic linking or loading of libraries. This is explained in the [redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246686.pdf) in chapter 5.

> Although Blue Gene/L uses the IBM XL
>   compilers, there are differences with
>   respect to all other IBM servers. In
>   particular, in the case of the IBM
>   pSeries Linux programming model, some
>   of the differences from Linux PPC64
>   are:
>
> - No stdin
> - No asynchronous I/O
> - No dynamic linking
> - No demand paging/swap
> - Virtual address space is mapped 1-on-1 with physical memory
> - No read-only memory
> - Due to CNK design decision – No SIGSEGV writing to a const char *p

Dynamic libraries are supported on BlueGene/P.

Comment: Actually, that seems to be from Chapter 5 of the linked redbook.